# how to compile on Windows 11 a fortran code written for Ubuntu

Tags: windows, compilation, fortran

I am attempting to compile Fortran code written for Ubuntu on Windows 11. Although one is functioning correctly, the other two executables (Vtk and Test) are not working and are producing an error. I have provided the error message. What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

```
C:\Pecube-master\bin>Vtk EXMP2
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
 Doing temperature and velocity
 Record           1
 doing record            0 out of           1
At line 65 of file Vtk.F90 (unit = 30)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'EXMP2/VTK/Pecube000.vtk': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.
```

Second error:

```
C:\Pecube-master\bin>Test EXMP2
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 Creating topo files
 creating Topo file
At line 268 of file testTopo.F90 (unit = 30)
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'EXMP2/VTK/Topo001.vtk': No such file or directory

Error termination. Backtrace:

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.


Backtrace for this error:
```

I know the source code should be changed to be compatible with windows, but I don't know exactly what I should look at in the source code. I tried to find `rm` command in the source code but couldn't find anything.

Comment: 1) Please specify which compiler/version you are using. 2) the error message are quite clear, in both cases your programs cannot open the file `"EXMP2/VTK/Pecube000.vtk"`. File paths on Windows use backslashs `\ ` instead of slashes `/`. So maybe you have to change all paths in the code, e.g. replace `EXMP2/VTK/Pecube000.vtk` with `EXMP2\VTK\Pecube000.vtk`. Or, you could compile and run your program in the WSL2 environment, without any modification.

Comment: The errors come from inside of your programs.  We need to see the relevant code and the actual location of your files. Regarding `rm`, that is a Unix command. MS DOS and MS Windows use `DEL` and `RMDIR` to delete files and directories.

Comment: @PierU The forward slashes `/` are perfectly fine on Windows. There is no need to use backslashes.

Comment: When searching for the relevant pert of the code for the `rm`, look for a `SYSTEM` or `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` command. It will have a`rm` inside. You will have to make an alternative for your windows. There is another option, to use a shell that recognizes Unix commands. For that you could run your program in an environment like Cygwin or perhaps in some Msys2 or Git bash, but I do not know if the right shell would then be used by the Fortran call. It has to be tried by someone who uses MS Windows.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава maybe you're right, but at the very least this will depend on the compiler... Since this code has some significant adherence to Unix, the easiest way would be to setup WSL2 with Ubuntu, and then compile and run the code inside WSL2.

Comment: @PierU No, it does not depend on the compiler. Windows accepts forward slashes in most APIs in general and always did. Maybe the cmd.exe might refuse them, I am not sure. Powershell will surely be OK.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/File-path-separator-for-Intel-Fortran-on-Windows/m-p/1279210#M155833

Comment: One way to portably remove a file in Fortran is to OPEN it, then immediately CLOSE it with `status="delete"`. Or since you seem to be using GFortran, there is the extension intrinsic `unlink` as well that can be used.

Comment: @PierU Even what is discussed by Steven does not depend on the compiler. It is the property of the particular API of the Windows themselves. But each compiler could in theory use a diffetent API under the hood. I eould be very surprised if the forward slashes were causing a real problem here.

Comment: Here is the link to have access to the source code. 

https://github.com/jeanbraun/Pecube

For now I installed wsl and have ubuntu app in my PC but still interested to know how this would work independently on windows. 
https://ubuntu.com/wsl

Comment: Please do not use comments to bring additionnal details, edit your question instead. In addition to the link to the gitub project, please provide direct links to the source files in which the errors are reported.